# converting MS SQL pivot query to MySQL pivot query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 7 tables in my MS-SQL database which I transferred to MySQL

```
protocols,
arms,
visit_groups,
visits,line_items,
line_items_visits,
services
```

and here is the picture of data into it:

1) protocol table

[image: protocol]

2) arms table

[image]

3) visit_groups table

[image]

4) visits table

[image]

5) line_items table

[image]

6) line_items_visits table

[image]

7) services table

[image]

I am performing a pivot operation on this in my MS SQL server and I am getting results as desired. here is the MS-SQL query and its result

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
set @query = 'SELECT id, name, serviceName, subject_count,' 
         + '[Visit 1],[Visit 2]' + ' FROM 
         (
            select protocols.id, arms.name, visit_groups.name as visitGroup, services.name as serviceName, 
            visits.quantity, 
            line_items_visits.subject_count
            from protocols,arms,visit_groups,visits,line_items,line_items_visits,services
            where protocols.id = arms.protocol_id
            and visit_groups.arm_id = arms.id
            and visits.visit_group_id = visit_groups.id
            and line_items_visits.arm_id = arms.id
            and visits.line_items_visit_id = line_items_visits.id
            and line_items_visits.line_item_id = line_items.id
            and services.id = line_items.service_id
            and protocols.id = ''' + '591' + '''
            and arms.id = ''' + '377' + '''

        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(quantity)
            for visitGroup in (' + '[Visit 1],[Visit 2]' + ')
        ) p';

 execute (@query)
```

and here is the result which I am getting

[image]

Now I transferred all my tables to mysql, and trying to run this query but I am not getting any result. can you help me in translating this pivot MS SQL operation into mysql query.

Comment: Why did you switch?

Comment: we have few other app which are mysql based and we are trying to come to common platform..to connect each app

Comment: I would be tempted to handle these sorts of display issues 'in-app'

Comment: aren't there any way in mysql to write this query ?

Comment: well we fetch the data in this format and then bind on a gridview

Comment: But isn't it simpler, quicker, and more scalable to do it in the app?

Comment: no, we want to move it to mysql, and that's the whole reason I posted this question. otherwise I would be using MS SQL.